# Delimiters in BIML

Tags: ssis, biml

I am migrating to biml for SSIS integration of flat, excel and CSV files and I want to know all the possible delimeters and text qualifiers we can use since the documentation isn't telling that much.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are 3 options to choose from:

1. The “official” ENUM
   Allowed values here are:
   – CRLF
   – CR
   – LF
   – Semicolon
   – Comma
   – Tab
   – VerticalBar
   – UnitSeparator
2. Use the Hex Code
   If you know the ASCII Code of your qualifier, you can use it starting with “*x” and ending with “*”.
   A ” would be described by “*x0022*” for example.
3. Use the actual character (HTML encoded or escaped)
   If you want to (for example) define a ” as your qualifier, you can do so. Just make sure, depending on how you use it, to either encode or escape it. When defining it as an actual Biml property, it has to be encoded.